# Referrer/URL Helper ee3?

Tags: ee3, plugin, global-variables

Really need the ability to grab the refering url that URL helper offered. Is this available for EE3 or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of late to the party, but I noticed Brian has an updated version of URL Helper in his github that looks ready for EE3, https://github.com/litzinger/URL-Helper/tree/master/third_party/url_helper